# Mac OS Terminal and Trash bin not working

Tags: terminal, mac, memory

Faced a problem using my MacBook Air 13 2017. I ran out of space (500mb free now). I tried to empty the trash bin, but it says that is not possible because there is no memory O_o. Having heard that it can be done through terminal. I open the terminal and have a white window saying "last login fri feb 11 18:22:42 on console        [process finished]". When I start a new window it tells the same. When I make a new command, whatever I type it tells the same. Seen here a solution with '\bin\bash -x -it still tells the same.

About half a year ago I had a problem also linked with no free memory, my mac refused working and a solution for this problem was using the terminal. But I couldn't use it because there was a similar problem with the terminal. I don't remember the details and how I solved this problem, but it was almost a miracle. After that I haven't used the terminal and now it behaves like that.

What can I do in such situation?

Comment: Try restarting your Mac in Safe Mode. It can free some disk space.

Answer (score 1):

500MB isn't enough free space on any drive.
A rule of thumb is you need 10-15% free space on a partition - more if the drive is tiny.

Do you have an external drive you can move data to?
If you hold Cmd as you drag to the external, the file will 'move' instead of copy, which is really a copy then delete - the resulting deletion will not go to trash, it will immediately create free space. Do this carefully, one large file at a time, just in case. Also make sure your backup is up to date.